# Is it possible to remove revision history of deleted files in GitHub

Tags: git, github

We are doing svn to git migration. We had around 5 big binary files ( each is around 700MB ) in SVN. So just deleted those files and migrated to GitHub. Now git source codes' size is less only. But git object pack is more than 8GB. I think because of these binary files revision. Shall I can remove these particular revision history ? Or anyway other way is there to clean up? We need remaining files' history.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command replacing FILE-TO-BE-REMOVED with the path to the file you want to remove, not just its filename. These arguments will:

- Force Git to process the entire history of every branch and tag
- Remove the specified file, as well as any empty commits generated as a result
- Overwrite your existing tags

> git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch FILE-TO-BE-REMOVED' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

Once you're happy with the state of your repository, force-push your local changes to overwrite your GitHub repository, as well as all the branches you've pushed up:

> git push origin --force --all